# How to generate Excel with macros programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to generate Microsoft Excel filse with macros embedded through a program?

There is a requirement to generate Excel files but the generated Excel should have some embedded macros.

We cannot just create Excel Plugin and generate plain Excel files, because the macro logic will be different based on the input parameter of the program writing the Excel.

Is this possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194611

> This article demonstrates how you can create a Microsoft Excel VBA
>   macro programmatically from Microsoft Visual Basic, call it, and
>   associate it with a toolbar button.